# Django : uploading too slow

Tags: django, nginx

I have a Django App running in Compute Engine(GCE) and my problem is that everytime I upload a not so large file like 1MB, the upload time is more than a minute. Is this normal? or I have mis-configuration somewhere in my code like maybe in Nginx.

I tested uploading 2 image files (1.2MB and 2.4MB) in my local and in the production site.

**1.2MB**

Local : 2 -3 seconds

Live : 50-60 seconds

**2.4 MB**

Local : 5-6 seconds

Live : 1.5 - 2 minutes

---

Python 2.7,Django 1.8 with nginx and uWSGI

Compute Engine instance : n1-standard-2 (2 vCPUs, 7.5 GB memory)

---

**nginx config**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-EDH-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:RSA-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-AES128:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';

    location / {
        include    uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass    unix:/sock/path/application.sock;
        uwsgi_read_timeout 600;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        alias /project/static_path/static/;
    }

    location /media  {
        alias /project/static_path/static/uploads;
    }

    location ~ /.well-known{
        allow all;
    }
}
```

**uwsgi config**

```
[uwsgi]
project_path = /project/path/
chdir = %(project_path)
home = /environment/path/
module = root.wsgi:application
master = true
processes = 5
socket = %(project_path)application.sock
chmod-socket = 666
vacuum = true
uid = current_user
gid = www-data
die-on-term = true
logto = /var/log/uwsgi/app/%n.log
```

**EDIT**

**nginx.conf**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {
        client_max_body_size 20M;
        client_header_timeout  3m;
        client_body_timeout    3m;
        send_timeout           3m;

        client_header_buffer_size    1k;
        large_client_header_buffers  4 4k;
    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";



    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: When you give the local and live times, are they running on the same server? Is local just the Django dev server or is it a local instance of Nginx + uWSGI + Django?

Comment: I am only running plain Django without Nginx and uWSGI in my local machine. In my production site I am using Django + Nginx + uWSGI.

Comment: I see. It shouldn't be happening because the uWSGI config looks fine. What's your base `nginx.conf` file like? You could try using `tcp_nopush` and `sendfile` with max chunk size to help, although I suspect it won't much difference. See [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html?&_ga=1.215363604.2092929002.1477558285#sendfile) for sendfile directive. Also, `tcp_nodelay` should be used with keep_alive connections. Again, I doubt any of this will help, but it's worth a shot

Comment: okay, will try this. Please see the nginx.conf.

Comment: What can you say with my server specs? maybe my server is just too slow.

Comment: I see you already have that in the config. Have you tried specifying `client_body_buffer_size         8k;` before?

Comment: Perhaps... It could be that your internet connection is slow, or that your server's internet connection is slow (not likely).

Comment: Have you checked request time breakdown in chrome network tab? What is taking the time - transferring the file, or getting server response afterwards? Try a simple html page with a file input field inside a form posting to the same url, see if it's fast. If it isn't then there is nothing but network problem. If it's fast then start adding extra layer until it slows down - uploading to python, to django.

Comment: Any solution? I am facing exact similar problem.